# Tracking E-commerce with google analytics isn't working

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout, google-analytics, google-api

I try to track the sold products in **Google Analytics**. But none of the sales show up in the e-commerce overview in Analytics. But visits are tracked.

The code is added in `configuration - > google api`.  and e-commerce is enabled in analytics. For checkout we are using the iwd one page checkout module.

Anyone knows what could be the problem?

Comment: This link might help you http://inchoo.net/magento/google-analytics-in-magento/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Magento Google API does not support e-commerce tracking out of the box.**

You will have to **use a 3rd party module** in order to track the ecommerce data.

From my experience I have used this module in the past and it worked fine for me you could give it a try: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-universal-analytics-1.html

On top of that, the fact that you're using a custom OPC module will probably lead you to modify the Google module in order to track the data properly.

Comment: Do you have any good suggestions for a 3rd party module. The magento version we are using is 1.9.

Comment: @Sjoerd I have added a link to my answer

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this problem , you can use this extension (https://marketplace.magento.com/conversionbug-enhancedecommerce.html )
 that will give Enhanced Ecommerce Tracking for Magento 2 .
3 http://www.tatvic.com/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-magento/

I think this can be helpful for you .

Comment: We are using magento 1.9

Comment: You can use these free extensions : 
1 .https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-1.html

2. https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-enhanced-ecommerce-for-magento.html